# Finding how many points to which a certain point is connected

Tags: computational-geometry

*This may be a programming issue, not a mathematical one. If so, please let me know so that I can rewrite it specifically for that audience.*

Consider a shape with a random border. Each point on its border has an x and y value that is an integer. This shape's interior is also composed of points that have integer values for both x and y. Each of these points is a distance of 1 from each other.

What is the most efficient way to get a total count of the points within that shape?

---

In case my question isn't clear enough, allow me to explain the specific issue I'm trying to solve.

It's a programming issue. I have an image that is divided up into different groups of pixels based on certain color analysis techniques. But I have no way of knowing when such a division occurs.

My program first analyzes all the pixels. In the process, it determines a specific pixel's "siblings" -- those that border it up, down, left, right and diagonally in each direction -- but that also satisfy a certain result from the color analysis I alluded to earlier. Therefore, one pixel's siblings can lead the program to *their* siblings, which lead the program to *their* siblings, and so on.

---

Beyond what I've written here, I'm having trouble offering a better formulation of this question. I'll happily edit my question if its current state is found lacking.

Comment: Do you know anything about the shape whether it is convex etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the corners are on lattice points, [Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) applies.  The area is the number of interior lattice points plus half the number on the border less $1$.  It sounds like you want to use it in reverse.  You can [triangulate the polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation), add the areas of the triangles, get the area, and know how many lattice points are involved.  To find the number of points on the border, given a segment from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ there are 1+GCD(c-a,d-b) points on it.  As the vertices will be double counted, you can just count each side as GCD(c-a,d-b)

Comment: Any mention of Pick's Theorem gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all points on the border you can find value of area, then you can use [Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) and get number of the point, that are in. Area you can find as $\sum\frac{y_i+y_{i+1}}{2}(x_{i+1}-x_i)$

Comment: See my comment on Ross' answer.